# java.net.SocketException caught when processing request to {}->http://ip:port: Permission denied: while registering selenium grid node through VPN

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, vpn, selenium-grid

I am trying to run Hub as:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub
```

Node as :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub http://ip:5555/grid/register -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="C:\new folder\IEDriverServer.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=chrome,version=latest,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=25,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
 I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://10.97.101.216:5555: Permission denied: connect
```

Also i have to connect and perform all this on VPN and so i am working on VPN.
Please help.

Comment: The solution for making the node and grid to work over vpn is to provide the hostname of your computer in the node registration URI. like  node URI  provided below by Deb where you mention the hub both the places enter hostname(go to windows commnad prompt and type hostname,it will give you the hostname) like -host hostname  -hub http://hostname:5557/grid/register -port 5558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things which you need to take care as follows :

- While you start the *Selenium Grid Node v2.53.x* you need to pass the *WebDriver* variant arguments in the begining as follows:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.0.105:4444/grid/register
  ```
- If you want to configure the *Selenium Grid Node v2.53.x* with specific browser version you need to be specific as follows:

  ```
  -browser "browserName=firefox,version=60.0.1,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=10.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
  ```
- Finally, ensure that you are using the proper **Grid Registration URI** as follows:

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.0.105:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,version=66.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=60.0.1,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=10.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
  ```
- **Selenium Grid Hub** logs:

  ```
  C:\Utility\SeleniumGrid>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub
  17:42:30.328 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
  2018-05-28 17:42:32.451:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2426ms
  17:42:32.469 INFO - Will listen on 4444
  17:42:32.540 INFO - Will listen on 4444
  2018-05-28 17:42:32.544:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
  2018-05-28 17:42:32.588:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5fdba6f9{/,null,AVAILABLE}
  2018-05-28 17:42:32.612:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@8b87145{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
  2018-05-28 17:42:32.613:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @2587ms
  17:42:32.613 INFO - Nodes should register to http://192.168.0.105:4444/grid/register/
  17:42:32.613 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
  17:51:43.893 INFO - Registered a node http://192.168.0.105:5555
  ```
- **Selenium Grid Node** logs:

  ```
  C:\Utility\SeleniumGrid>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.0.105:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,version=66.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=firefox,version=60.0.1,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver" -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=10.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"
  17:51:42.250 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
  17:51:42.317 INFO - Adding browserName=chrome,version=66.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver
  17:51:42.318 INFO - Adding browserName=firefox,version=60.0.1,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver
  17:51:42.318 INFO - Adding browserName=internet explorer,version=10.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver
  17:51:43.696 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01
  17:51:43.696 INFO - OS: Windows 8 6.2 amd64
  17:51:43.702 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision a36b8b1
  17:51:43.751 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
  17:51:43.752 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
  17:51:43.759 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN817:51:43.761 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
  17:51:43.762 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
  17:51:43.788 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
  17:51:43.790 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
  17:51:43.792 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1b68b9a4
  17:51:43.793 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
  17:51:43.794 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
  17:51:43.795 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
  17:51:43.799 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
  17:51:43.799 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@25af5db5
  17:51:43.800 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
  17:51:43.833 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
  17:51:43.834 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://192.168.0.105:4444/grid/register
  17:51:43.894 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
  ```

Comment: I am still getting the following error(I am on VPN):05:28:37.142 INFO - Retrying request to {}->http://10.97.101.216:4444
05:28:37.157 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Permission denied: connect                                       (I used the following for launching node)java  -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\\Users\\Public\\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.97.101.216:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet explorer,version=11.1029.15063.0,maxInstances=5,seleniumProtocol=WebDriver"             i

Comment: But when i am disconnecting from VPN it gets registered successfully.

Comment: @AbhinayKumar Great !!! So the issue is the connectivity through VPN and our _Selenium Grid Hub_ and _Selenium Grid Node_ is perfect.

Comment: I have to work on VPN so isnt there any solution for VPN.

Comment: @AbhinayKumar This is a typical VPN connectivity issue and you can get well researched answers either on [**Super User**](https://superuser.com/tour) or [**Server Fault**](https://serverfault.com/tour)

Comment: It is working fine even on VPN .Just need to provide the VPN ipv4 address in node registration URI.

Comment: @AbhinayKumar I feel the step _to provide the VPN ipv4 address in node registration URI_ is important. Can you update the main question with this relevant info so this question can be useful to future readers?

Comment: The point brought up about the VPN issue was a life saver. Glad this was on SO. Using the IPv4 address didn't work for me (IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . 162.273.80.80) (possibly UE) but disconnecting from Cisco AnyConnect solved the issue. Selenium server works great.

Comment: @Fractal Thanks for the feedback. Glad to be able to help.